# Find unique elements within a certain range of coordinates

Tags: python, unique, element

I'm trying to determine all unique elements within a list based on the x-y-coordinates. The list looks like the following structure:

```
List =[[[Picture1, [X-Coordinate, Y-Coordinate]], [Picture1, [X-Coordinate, Y-Coordinate]]],
      [[Picture2, [X-Coordinate, Y-Coordinate]], [Picture2, [X-Coordinate, Y-Coordinate]]],
      ....]
```

This is the actuall list:

```
MyList = [[['IMG_6094.jpg', [2773.0, 240.0]], ['IMG_6094.jpg', [2773.0, 240.0]]],
         [['IMG_6096.jpg', [1464.0, 444.0]], ['IMG_6096.jpg', [3043.0, 2358.0]]],
         [['IMG_6088.jpg', [1115.5, 371.5]]],
         [['IMG_6090.jpg', [3083.0, 1982.5]], ['IMG_6090.jpg', [3083.0, 1982.5]]],
         [['IMG_6093.jpg', [477.0, 481.0]], ['IMG_6093.jpg', [450.0, 487.5]]]]
```

As you can see, there are sometimes elements that have the same coordinates within a picture or are at least very close to each other. What I need to do is to throw out all non-unique or very close elements based on one of the coordinates (doesn't matter if its x or y). 
The list should look like this:

```
MyList = [[['IMG_6094.jpg', [2773.0, 240.0]], --- thrown out because copy of first element ---],
         [['IMG_6096.jpg', [1464.0, 444.0]], ['IMG_6096.jpg', [3043.0, 2358.0]]],
         [['IMG_6088.jpg', [1115.5, 371.5]]],
         [['IMG_6090.jpg', [3083.0, 1982.5]], --- thrown out because copy of first element---],
         [['IMG_6093.jpg', [477.0, 481.0]], --- thrown out because e.g. abs(x-coordinates) < 30]
```

Could someone provide a elegant solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is this not a dict of tuples? This data structure seems very inefficient

Comment: Also please provide what you have tried and where it went wrong so we can help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  This is not a site to hand you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you create for img a list of innteger that are close to it, than for the other points on that img, you check if their x or y or in the list, and if so add them to the remove list
btw when removing using the index make sure to start with largest x,y so you don't change the lower point index before removing them

```
 remove = []
 close = 30
 for i in range(len(MyList)):
     xList = []
     yList = []
     for j in range(len(MyList[i])):
         if int(MyList[i][j][1][0]) in xList or int(MyList[i][j][1][1]) in yList:
             remove.append([i,j])
             continue
         x = int(MyList[i][j][1][0])
         y = int(MyList[i][j][1][1])
         xList+= list(range(x-close,x+close))
         yList+= list(range(y-close,y+close))
```